# Is MyISAM Table locking in MySQL automatic?

Tags: mysql, myisam

Does MySQL automatically peform read / write table locks on MyIsam tables, or do I have to explicitly lock the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond making reasonable efforts to make certain statements atomic, MyISAM doesn't have the concept of transactions and its related row level locking.

Therefore, you should use `LOCK TABLES` to avoid race conditions or data inconsistencies when you use multiple statements (e.g. a `SELECT` statement followed by multiple related `UPDATE` statements).

Answer (score 1):

See here about [Pros and Cos Of  MyISAM](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-myisam-table-pros-con/)

[MyISAM's About Internal Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html)

MyISAM uses table-level locking. When a row is inserted or updated, all other changes to that table are held up until that request has been completed.

Correct me if 'm wrong